# development symbian application for cellulars that has GPS

Tags: symbian, mobile-phones, cellular-network

i want to develop symbian application 
that uses the GPS of the cellulars.

for which version of symbian do i need to develop
and which phones does it supported ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense - what is "GPS of the cellulars"?
Do you want to make a Symbian application for phones with built in GPS? Or do you want to make a Symbian application for phones which support some some of positioning based on cell location triangulation? or something else?
This is probably a good starting point:
http://www.forum.nokia.com/Technology_Topics/Mobile_Technologies/Location-Based_Services/

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop for Symbian S60 V3 and newer.

Here is a list of [phones with GPS receiver](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia-phones-f-1-11.php) that will be supported

Answer (score 0):

This kind of applications are known as LBS applications.
Actually, you can develop for S60 and S40 platform. So, you will have to decide.

You can find more information about each platform on Forum Nokia website.
http://www.forum.nokia.com/Technology_Topics/Mobile_Technologies/Location-Based_Services/